# Passing a command to 'find -exec' through a variable does not work

Tags: bash, unix

given a directory `$HOME/foo/` with files in it.

the command:

`find $HOME/foo -type f -exec md5deep -bre {} \;`

works fine and hashes the files.

but, creating a variable for `-exec` does not seem to work:

`md5="md5deep -bre"`

`find $HOME/foo -type f -exec "$md5" {} \;`

returns: `find: md5deep -bre: No such file or directory`

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are enclosing your variable in double quotes, the entire string gets sent to `find` as a single token following `-exec` and `find` treats it as the name of the command.  To resolve the issue, simply remove the double quotes around your variable:

```
find "$HOME/foo" -type f -exec $md5 {} \;
```

In general, it is not good to store commands in shell variables.  See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: If you want to decrease the command length, it's preferable to create a function or a script and run it as part of `-exec`. like `find $HOME/foo -type f -exec ./md5.sh {} \;`

Comment: @JonathaDaguerre A function wouldn't work with `-exec`, since that's executed by `find`, and functions are only available in the shell. (But a helper script would work fine.)

Comment: Good point @GordonDavisson! To run a function from `-exec` it would need a new call to the shell. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array.

```
md5Cmd=(md5deep -bre)

find "$HOME/foo" -type f -exec "${md5Cmd[@]}" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better still, make the whole -exec statement optional:

```
md5Cmd=( -exec md5deep -bre {} \; )
find "$HOME/foo" -type f "${md5Cmd[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the syntax for `find -exec` a bit weird (with several pitfalls as the ones @codeforester has mentioned).

So, as an alternative, i tend to separate the *search* part from the *action* part by piping the output of `find` (or `grep`) to a proper `xargs` process.

For example, i find it more readable (`-n1` for using exactly 1 argument per command):

```sh
find $HOME/foo -type f | xargs -n1 md5deep -bre
```